# How can I use Web Sockets AND A (database) User system to alter what data is sent?

Tags: php, sql, database, sockets, web

I have a basic knowledge of websockets and I've set a web socket sever up on my VPS host.

I have a user system with database. I was planning on having a table called 'chat_log' too.

I want to use my web socket sever on different pages.

Say for example on each user's profile there was a chat.

I'd have a column in the database of to where the chat was posted to. Then it would run a query to check where the chat was posted to, if it was posted there display it.

Could I achieve the same effect (combining PHP database techniques) with web sockets to create a chat based on database results?

Also another thing, how could I send where the chat was posted to? If it's not sent? Is there a way of getting the GET variable from the URL in javascript and sending that DATA separately, so it can be processed in the php?

Comment: This would depend on what "web socket server" you are using. Whichever you chose should have some sort of database access layer you can use to query.

Comment: Jonathan Kuhn, it's a PHP sever. Problem is how do I get the data from the url on the "chat room page" send that to the sever ($chat_num) and send the chat at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you pass the $_GET variable to javascript which then pass it to your websocket server? Assuming your websocket server has a database connection.